# How to configure C++ Builder compiler to output just exe?

Tags: c++, c++builder

The question is how to configure in C++ Builder 2010 compiler and debug option to output just one exe file, and all the other inside of that, so that I can easily use program on other machine without installing them, with just running exe file.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

With all versions of C++Builder you don't need to make an installer for this, (although Inno Setup is simply brilliant if you do require one).

Just select the following project options:-

- **Project/Packages:,** Build with Runtime Packages = DISABLED
- **C++/Linker:** Dynamic RTL = FALSE

That's it. You will get a single exe with no dependencies (apart from any 3rd party DLL's you use. All your VCL components (including third party ones) will get statically linked.

I use this mode for all production builds (although I do then use Inno Setup installer to manage the install/removal process for customers).

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Roddy's answer:
Do not forget to disable CodeGuard (Project->Options->Codeguard) or your program will fail on any machine that does not has the CodeGuard DLL's installed !